# Async loader not working in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Here is my async loader. It is just call a api then add response with source file and return that. But its not work. Can anyone help me?

```
const path = require('path');
const request = require('request');


function assetAdd(source){
    var pathObj = path.parse(this.resourcePath);
    var callback = this.async();
    if (pathObj.base === 'index.js'){
        request({url:'http://localhost:8282/mockAsset'}, function(err, response, body) {
            source += body;
            callback(null, source);
        });
    }else{
        callback(null, source);
    }
}

module.exports = assetAdd;
```

Comment: Try to elaborate on what "its not work" means. Describe the current and the expected behavior.

Comment: I have not add else condition in my loader. Now edit my question its working fine.